# Why in the unit test components always use `should <action>` phrase form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, components

In a lot of javascript libraries (e.g [react-dom test](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete/__tests__/VAutocomplete.spec.ts)) I have used or in components libraries (e.g [Vuetify component](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete/__tests__/VAutocomplete.spec.ts))
For its unit test are using the `should` form: `should not respond to click`

1. This form is a unit test standard?
2. Where could I find more information about it?

In my personal opinion a prefer to use `Given? - When - Then` form from BDD testing, but if `should form` is very popular I want to know why and then adopt it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form is specific to the use of Jest `it(...)` function that represents a subject and was inherited from Jasmine, also applicable to `test(...)`. It reads as "it should ..." or "test should ...".

It doesn't make a good sentence with `test()` because it's usually a tested unit that should do something, not a test.

In test reports, `describe` description becomes a subject:

```
describe('Foo' => {
  it('should have a button', ...);
  it('should do a request', ...);
});
```

reads as

```
Foo
  ✓ should have a button
  ✓ should do a request
```

This makes less sense if there's no `describe` block, this wasn't allowed in Jasmine but is allowed in Jest.

A downside of this convention is that test reports are polluted with "should" word. "should" can be omitted for this reason so it becomes "has a button" and "does a request" instead of "should have a button" and "should do a request".